# PrestaShop to mobile app

Tags: mobile, prestashop, hybrid-mobile-app

I was asked to make a mobile app (native or hybrid) for an existing prestashop website. 
What would be the best option for you? I considered:

- Services which connect to your API and generate a full Native app, but I never used them so I may not know some cons for this scenario
- Services which basically wrap your website in a Webview and use some background logic for push notifications and other stuff
- Hand-made mobile app using prestashop api, which seems the most "difficult" option and isn't very documented over the internet.

Thank you!

Comment: Which is the difference between point 1 and 3?

Comment: @tarekfellah The first option is to let other services generate your app (with a few options for customizing it) and the 3rd is to hand-make it from the beginning to the end

Comment: I prefer using 3rd option, prestashop webservice is not complicated and you can found examples on presta forum, mobile app is preferable you can use geolocalisation and phone capabilities

Comment: @tarekfellah Hi tarek, I am stuck creating carts and orders from android native application, I am trying to use Prestashop API but I can't figure out how to do it, would you share some forum to help?

Comment: @Jotadrive you can check here https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/469152-help-step-by-step-to-create-order-via-webservice/

Comment: @tarekfellah that post is quite interesting. Sorry for my questions but, can it be done via JSON instead XML? And, Can I create and order without create user? Thank you very much

Comment: @Jotadrive I don't think it's possible with JSON, also user is required, if user already existant you have not to add it